# Excel VBA - Open input box in word from Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that transfers tables to specific bookmarks in the word document, then i have created code to then save the word document as a PDF. The below is what i have, but when i run it, the input box sits in excel, which is not visible as the focus has switched to the Word document. Is there a way to come back to the excel so the i can use input box?

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPDFname As String

'Save PDF
strPDFname = InputBox("Enter Client Name for Report", "PDF Version of Report", " - Tree Condition Report " & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy"))
    If strPDFname = "" Then 'user deleted text from inputbox, add default name
        strPDFname = "example"
    End If
    strPath = myDoc.Path
    If strPath = "" Then    'doc is not saved yet
        strPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        'just add \ at the end
        strPath = strPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    myDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                                       strPath & strPDFname & ".pdf", _
                                       ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                       OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                       OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                       Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                       IncludeDocProps:=True, _
                                       CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, _
                                       BitmapMissingFonts:=True
```

I wanted to copy tables into word, then save as PDF, with an input box that allows me to note file name.

Comment: There are file dialogs that are readily available and much more user-friendly than any `InputBox` could ever be... Have you tried `Application.GetOpenFileName`, for example?

Comment: Does the Excel VBA code have a reference to the Word `Application` object?

Comment: `AppActivate` should help give the focus to the application you need focused.

Comment: Hi I simplified it with Macro to save to same folder, thanks for help